# Help, can I still fix this?

Tags: repair, wood, doors, bedroom

[image]

A few weeks ago, the door knob started to become loose with greyish wood/sand chunks falling out of the gap between the doorknob and the door. Currently thinking of getting a handyman in to have a look but just want some opinions on whether it’s still fixable and if it’s worth it. TIA

Comment: It looks like the screws are loose can you find them and tighten them they may be on the other side of the door

Comment: Does the round back plate on the knob assembly actually fit inside the hole drilled in the door? From looking at the picture this seems to be the case but please confirm because this will have an impact on a proper answer.

Answer (score 8):

Yes, this can be remedied by using a "goof plate" pictured below.  If the outer diameter of the lockset is 2" or larger this plate will work.  I do believe they make smaller ones if the lockset is smaller.  The UPC for this product is 049793095244- Model # U-9524.  Package includes 2 pieces-One for each side.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The knob hole looks larger than the knob.  **I want to know if the hole is 2-1/8" (54mm) diameter**.   If it is, then you have a standard doorknob hole, but the wrong doorknob assembly.

If it is larger than 2-1/8", then have the landlord or home insurer fix it, because this is a big, big mistake! *What were they thinking?* There is no reason I know of to drill a knob hole oversize.  If it is oversize, then decide if you're *in love with* the door.  If not, just replace the door - it will be easier than trying to glue a plug in there, and a lot more secure if it's an outside door.

### How to get the knob off

The screws are covered by a vanity plate, because people don't like seeing screws and because they want to be able to change vanity plates for different knob colors.  The vanity plate is the pretty cylinder up against the door.

Look for a latch or a catch to release it from the actual backing plate. Also, look for a small tuck-under" maybe 3/16" long, pinch the disc at the points 90 degrees around from there and try to pull it or slide it toward or away.

With a normal knob, you typically need to remove the doorknob, but with that type of handle it may just slide over.

With the vanity plate gone, you should be looking at a steel plate and two screw heads. It's straightforward from there.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing the outer ring of the back-plate unscrews to reveal the two machine screws that hold the handles on the door.

It looks like the face of the door was drilled too big for the chosen handle.

The proper fix is to replace the handles with ones designed for that size of hole or to replace the door.

it may be possible to cut a ledge around the aperature with a router
and then fit a plywood cover that spans the opening, drill the cover for the latch axle and the handle bolts, fill the cracks sand and paint

The lazy fix is to put some sort of metal plate to span the gap, you might find a flat stainless plumbing escutcheon that does the job.

To do it almost-right remove the handles, clean the surface of the void then fill the edges of the void with 2 part plastic filler, you can use cardboard tubes or drinking straws etc to keep the filler from blocking the screw-holes etc, this filler has a strong chemical smell for a few days, so you you may want to remove the door first. This is basically the same stuff as automotive body filler. it sets hard, but before it's fully cured it can be trimmed with a knife etc. when it is cured sand, paint, and re-fit the handles.